# GLSL Transform Feedback return Array vs Vector

Tags: c++, c, opengl, vector, glsl

When I declare an array of structs explicitly my transform feedback loop works perfectly.

```
struct FeedBackInfo
    {
            float area;
            float Pabs;
            float Pref;
    }

FeedBackInfo FBI[36];
....
....
glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0,sizeof(FBI), FBI);
```

However, I'd like to not limit myself to the 36 point box that I've created for my sample program and be able to scale up depending on the model loaded.  But when I try to switch to a vector object that can be dynamically allocated I am unable to get the transform feedback to work.

```
struct FeedBackInfo
{
    float area;
    float Pabs;
    float Pref;
};

std::vector<FeedBackInfo> FBI;
FBI.resize(36);
....
....
```

This will fail outright

```
glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0,sizeof(FBI), &FBI);
```

This will only fill in a few of the values in an offset manor

```
glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0,sizeof(FBI), &FBI[0]);
```

I cannot even itterate 0 through 35 and fill in all of the data, only the areas are being filled in.

I do not understand why an explicit declaration of the array of structs will work smoothly and why transforming it into a vector object suddenly doesn't work.

Is there a way to dynamically allocate the struct of FeedBackInfo and still work smoothly with the transform feedback loop?

Comment: Have you tried using an iterator: i.e. `FBI.begin()`?

Comment: Place the iterator where, in the glGetBufferSubData call?

Comment: I have to use sizeof because sizeof returns the memory footprint of FBI, FBI.size() would return the length of the vector. Putting in the iterator did not work either.

Comment: Uh, because `sizeof(vector)` does **not** give the memory footprint of the data stored in the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<FeedBackInfo> FBI;
FBI.resize(36);
```

Your `sizeof(FBI);` wont be the size of the memory you want.
If you want to have the size of the memory (of the data, not of the vector) you need to use `FBI.size()*sizeof(FeedBackInfo)`

```
glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, FBI.size()*sizeof(FeedBackInfo), FBI.data());
```

I replaced your `&FBI[0]` with `FBI.data()` because I think it's better to read..